# Python equivalen to clean() function in Excel

Tags: python-3.x, regex, excel-formula

In Excel there is a function called `clean()`, which removes all nonprintable characters from text. Reference [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/clean-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41#:~:text=Removes%20all%20nonprintable%20characters%20from,files%20and%20cannot%20be%20printed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/clean-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41#:%7E:text=Removes%20all%20nonprintable%20characters%20from,files%20and%20cannot%20be%20printed).

I am wondering if there is any direct `function/method in python` to achieve the same.

Also, how can I mimic `clean()` function in `python` just using `Regular expression`?

Any pointer will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CLEAN` function in Excel removes only "the first 32 nonprinting characters in the 7-bit ASCII code (values 0 through 31)", according to the documentation you link to, so to mimic it, you can filter characters of a given string whose `ord` values are less than 32:

```
def clean(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in s if ord(c) < 32)
```

Or you can use a regular expression substitution to remove characters with hex values between `\x00` and `\x1f`:

```
import re

def clean(s):
    return re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1f]+', '', s)
```